# Deleting a hyphen from a text file output, but not the hyphen on negative numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have a text file with lots of numbers, one integer/float per line.
Blank lines with no data are indicated with a '-' and id like to remove the hyphen with code.  But, while doing that, avoid removing the hyphen from negative numbers (-4 etc).
Is this possible to begin with?

I have tried using `str.replace` and `str.split` with no success as it either removes all the hyphens or none.

Comment: post sample data of text file

Comment: If it's a single `-` on a line by itself, you can read the text file line by line, and remove/skip the lines that contain just the `-`.

Comment: What have you already tried? Where did you stuck?

Comment: If you have access to the `sed` program (generally available on any *nix operating system), it'll be much simpler and faster than to code it in Python, in particular if it's to replace the dash with an empty or no line in the text file itself.

Comment: @00 How would i do that using code?  It is just an otherwise blank line with a -.  Using a for loop maybe?

Comment: Yes: loop through the lines in the while, which in Python is an iteration over the file pointer itself (see e.g. [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)).

Comment: This question is pretty clear but it would be easier for people to answer if you included an example of the data in the file in your question as well as some example expected outputs.

Answer (score 0):

this will remove all trailing `-` from the line. If the line contained spaces you can change `num.rstrip("-")` to `num.strip().rstrip("-")`

```
with open("your_file") as fp:
    file_content = [num for num in fp if num.rstrip("-")]
```